# Performance testing a WordPress site locally?

Tags: performance

G'day, I am a novice in Wordpress development, I have searched a lot but couldn't find the solution. I have developed a Wordpress site and I want to test it on localhost, I want to test the server performance, speed, system operations like bandwidth issues, server load and busyness etc. Can anyone help please? In other words I want to test my site and generate the results that how will my WP site perform if 100s of users access my website. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to test it on localhost if this doesnt reflect your real server envirement?

You can do these kind of test (but not on localhost) with a website called https://www.blitz.io/

It shows you exactly the response times for your server, how many users it can handle till producing errors, etc.

But you need to do this with a real server, not on localhost. If you test it on localhost the result won't say anything about the real performance on a real webserver.